# How can I repair the bent legs on my couch?

Tags: wood-repair

I could really use some advice on repairing the legs on my couch.

As seen below, the two legs on the left side are tilting (it's not as visible on the other side):

[image: Couch profile.]

I also snapped a picture of the small "compartment" inside of the couch (between the two legs on the left side), revealing some damage:

[image: Couch inside.]

The yellow material behind the plywood is some sort of foam.

I don't really know what to do and would appreciate any pointers. If more information is needed I will provide it. I'm sorry if this question isn't appropriate for this site and will adjust it as needed or remove it if required.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. You're going to have to make this look worse before you can make it better, that mess of screws (which are WAAAY too short!), nails and brads needs to cleared out of the way before you can attempt to position things correctly and start to repair. This will actually require further disassembly, which might be more than you want to take on.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long did this last before it began to fail? Or was it doing fine until an accident of some kind broke it suddenly?

Comment: Hey @Graphus, thanks for helping me. I understand. It's probably a bit too advanced for me then. With my skillset, It'll probably not be impossible to attach four 2x4's as suggested in the answer below. The couch lasted for maybe close to 7-8 years? And the legs started bending maybe 1-2 years ago. Although I'm not really sure.

Comment: Well you got a good few years out of it then, that's not too bad. I know many people who'd want to replace a sofa anyway after approximately as long as you've had it. Good luck with the propping up, it should be simple to do and very sturdy.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really complain! To clarify, the legs started bending after 7-8 years, meaning that it's been in use for around 10 years. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about your couch man. That freakin' sucks.

The amount of work it would take you to get this piece of furniture ship-shape, based on its construction, is probably more than it is worth.

I've had similar problems with a similar quality of construction piece of furniture and opted against a full repair.

That said, if getting a new couch immediately is not an option and you need still need a couch I think you are in luck. I suggest putting it "up on blocks" -- something to git'er'done, until you can replace the couch.

Like the other commenter has said, a repair back to 100% or even 90% is probably going to entail taking the thing apart. As any DIY furniture person can tell you, with new tools and materials even seemingly simple fixes can get pretty expensive pretty fast. But if time and money (emphasis on time) are abundant (emphasis on abundant) then it is probably possible since nothing looks that badly broken.

But I'd guess you're in a similar situation I was in with my couch where you just wanna watch TV and not have a pile of couch parts in the living room for weeks and weeks.

So, here's my thoughts on something down and dirty. Since the seat and the arm rest appear to be made of separate plywood carcasses, you should be able to discretely (read, not totally awful aesthetically) take the load off the failed leg/armrest module. From the looks of it a rough installation of four 2x4s in a box shape attached to the plywood from which the seat is constructed could be sturdy enough for most couch activities as long as whatever screw joint you come up with is snug and stout.

You could probably get away with literally putting it up on blocks, something like two off cuts from a 4x4 could suffice. That's what I ended up doing. But your couch is also much more stylish than mine was so I am guessing the hoopdie-chic option won't fly.

Hope that helps you on your way!

Comment: Hi @YoStephen, both solutions sound great and I will definitely try to make it work (maybe the four 2x4's first). Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking and great first Answer.

Comment: Instead of adding posts you might be able to move the legs inwards so they support the main body of the couch directly

Comment: @ratchetfreakRat ooh that's quite an elegant solution. As long as the carcass from which the armrest is built isn't totally compromised this is for sure the most economical and aesthetic fix